# How to set a dynamic name to a PDF range from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, pdf

I am looking at creating a PDF from an excel document. I only need part of the worksheet to become part of the PDF. The naming convention of the PDF needs to be dynamic as it is a quotation document.

I have tried the below code already. This is so we can attach the document to an email or build the code to deliver the email to a customer but currently it is failing to run.

````
```Sub SetEmailToPDF()
ChDir "S:\PDF Quotes"
Worksheets("Email").Range("A1:F70").ExpportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"S:\PDF Quotes-" & Format(Now, "DDMMYY") & Worksheets("Email").Range("c12") & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub```
````

What i expect this to do is produce is a PDF with the file name of `120419Companyname.pdf` and this should be saved in `s:\PDF Quotes`

I have also tried to simplfy to the below code and still get the 438 run time error:

```
Sub SetEmailToPDF()
ChDir "S:\PDF Quotes"
Worksheets("Email").Range("A1:F70").ExpportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"S:\PDF Quotes\test.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. u have two bugs. first  ExpportAsFixedFormat  has a exta "p", it should be ExportAsFixedFormat and second on the file name "S:\PDF Quotes-" must be "S:\PDF Quotes\". good luck

Comment: Thank you so much i feel a bit silly now haha

Comment: dont worry. it happends to all. hehe